# Can we use refreshToken long time?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I using oAuth to interact with Google Analytics API. For the first time, I am getting authCode and refreshToken. Can I use refreshToken for permanent? Because I have to make a call Google Analytics API to get analytics data and display it in application in different formats.

Can anyone tell me what is the life time of refreshToken ? Is it permanent or valid for few days ? I have done some R&D on it. I could find somewhere it's valid for 14days/60days. And also somewhere I found that it's permanent. I am in confusion.

Help will be appreciated, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refreshToken is not permanent, but can last indefinitely if not revoked. it can be revoked a couple ways:

1. from the google account security page, the user can manually revoke permission to the app.
2. google will automatically revoke the refresh token if the user changes their password AND the scopes include a mail scope. This was new in december 2015 and Google has changed that rule recently to only happen for mail scopes and to not do it for marketplace apps and apps script apps, see https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/09/update-increased-account-security-via.html

the google guidelines show how to handle a revoked token scenario.

Comment: In my case, I am using my gmail account to read my website analytics data. So I will not change password and will not revoke access as well. So in this case my regreshToken will be active long time/permanent, Correct ?

Comment: correct, unless google changes the rules in the future.